# C# Async return type conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I was implementing Asynchronous method in WCF service and I found that Async return only three return type-

1. Void
2. Task
3. `Task<T>`

Now I am facing a datatype conversion as mention in the below code.

Calling Asynchronous method of return type Task

```
public async Task<DataView> ExecuteDV(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{

    exceptionMessage = string.Empty;
     resultType = (int)Helper.ServiceActionType.Success;
    var table = new DataTable();
    DataView dv = null;
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBAccess.ConnString))
        {
            sqlCommand.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(dr);

            if (table.Rows != null && table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                dv = table.DefaultView;
            }
            else
            {
                resultType = (int)Helper.ServiceActionType.DataNotFound;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        //Logging Code
    }
    return dv;

}
```

And the called method which has a data type as DataView. Now I want ExecuteDV(sqlCommand) to convert back to DataView.Because in other method I am mapping the return parameters to respective fields.

```
public DataView RetrieveHushDailySummaryRecords(SqlCommand sqlCommand)
{
    return ExecuteDV(sqlCommand);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use that `async` keyword? You don't use any async code inside that method!

Comment: Please find the updated code. I don't want the method to wait for the response. If other request is called the method should work as parallel execution. As per the above code I found "GenerateCodeAsync().Result". But it will wait for the response

Comment: Right now, the code doesn't contain any asynchronous method. In any case, `async` *doesn't* make a method run asynchronously if it isn't already asynchronous. It only allows you to use the `await` keyword, which allows you to process the return values of asynchronous methods without blocking and without any conversions. If eg. you add a `Task<string> GenerateCodeAsync()` method, you can process its results by writing `string results=await GenerateCodeAsync();`

Comment: You'll need to use `dr = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync()` ([see MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereaderasync.aspx)) for this method to be really asynchronous. But Immediately waiting for the final result sort of defeats that purpose.

Comment: @SanJaisy: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/bchristie/9926cd7da7119b70223c

Comment: A different HttpRequest usually runs in a different thread, so that already will execute "in parallel".

Comment: I am facing the error while converting from Task<Dataview> to DataView.Error as "Cannot Convert from system.threading.dataview to system.data.dataview ".

Comment: @Brad Christie -  I show ur suggestion. Can u Please tell me how to catch the response from another class with dataview as datatype.

Comment: @SanJaisy: If the other method is async, you can `await ExecuteDataViewAsync(...)`. If it's not, you need to wrap it (there are examples, but look for "AsyncHelper" (a quick google search shows [one such example](https://gist.github.com/ChrisMcKee/6664438)).

Comment: If the method is taking many request like : ordering item on same time by multiple users........ is is good to apply asynchronous concept?? In some scenario the response is also depends.I Want to make the performance faster??